# Slideshow in ie -slowly loading with frames

Tags: jquery

Have problem with jquery 
when using cycle() for large images (~100Kb) 
IE8 show tham as frames.
I.e. there is any smooth which changing ...

```
//activate rotator
$('#home').cycle({
    activePagerClass:       'activeSlide',
    timeout:                '10000',
    pager:                  '#home-pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder:     function(idx, slide) { 
    // return selector string for existing anchor 
    return '#home-pager li:eq(' + idx + ')'; 
    }
});
```

How it is activated. It show 4 frames (~1kb each) with images (40-100Kbs and 800*500px).
Pls suggest, maybe anybody have this issue? 
Which rotator with fade effect use for large images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. fx: helps change situation
2. Speed: helps change  situation
3. Image preloading is most usefull